# Change BPP in Bitmap Image

Tags: c, linux, bitmap

ive captured an image using xlib XGetImage and saved it to bitmap, the problem is the bitmap is 32 BPP and i MUST convert that bitmap to 24 BPP, any ideas? maybe make XGetImage get a 24 BPP image or convert the 32 BPP Bitmap to 24 BPP?

thanks.

Comment: you need a program to do it, or you just need to convert 1 bitmap that you saved?

Comment: i need to convert it before saving

Answer (score 0):

Use the convert utility from the ImageMagick software suite. It is very portable and found on almost every unix/linux system out there.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

First save your file using XWriteBitmapFile to a file named original.xbm, and then use a convert command similar to: `convert -depth 24 original.xbm converted.xbm`.

If you need you can do a lot more conversions using this tool (like resizing, blurring, cropping, etc ...).